# Installing sbt on Windows 10 for Scala course

Tags: scala, sbt, installation

Instructions for the course say to use verion 0.13.x.
I installed the latest msi from the sbt site, but when I type "sbt about", I get:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\reall>sbt about
Error: Unable to access jarfile
Copying runtime jar.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Error: Unable to access jarfile
"C:\Users\reall\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.2"\jars\sbt.jar"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\reall\project
[info] Set current project to reall (in build file:/C:/Users/reall/)
[info] This is sbt 1.0.2
[info] The current project is {file:/C:/Users/reall/}reall 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.12.3
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, sbt.plugins.Giter8TemplatePlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.12.3
```

i.e., a jar file error and the sbt version 1.0.2.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong, it's just that the required version `0.13.x` is not the latest anymore. So you can either follow @dmytro-mitin's answer and reinstall sbt, or you can still **use the one you already have**: what you installed now is the [*sbt launcher*](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Launcher-Getting-Started.html), it can be used to run different versions of sbt depending on a project. So it's not important which launcher version you are using (unless you're working on something very sbt-specific).

Normally, every sbt project has a `project/build.properties` file with the sbt version that is needed to work with it:

```
sbt.version=0.13.16
```

So you can change (or create) this file and when you run `sbt` in the project root folder, it will launch sbt version 0.13.16.

Another way to launch specific version of sbt is to run it with the `-sbt-version` option :

```
sbt -sbt-version 0.13.16
```

or using `-D` flag:

```
sbt -Dsbt.version=0.13.16
```

which has exactly the same effect as editing `project/build.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Install not the latest version. The latest one is 1.0.2.

Install 0.13.16.

You can download it here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html

There are [msi](https://cocl.us/sbt-0.13.16.msi) and [zip](https://cocl.us/sbt-0.13.16.zip) files.

[Installing sbt on Windows](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Windows.html)