# Running a sbt command from windows powershell - Unable to access jar

Tags: windows, scala, powershell, jar, sbt

I am trying to run a program I found on `GitHub`. I am new to `sbt`, and using `Window powershell`. After trying a few variations and having a look for similar `unable to access jar` problems, I haven't yet found a fix. Is anyone able to provide me some insight?

My input and the error are in the image link below. Thanks in advance!

```
\NewMotion\ocpp> sbt "project example-json-client" "run 01234567 ws://localhost:8017/ocppws 1.6" 

Error: Unable to access jarfile
Copying runtime jar.

The filename, dictionary name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Error: Unable to access jarfile

\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.4"\jars\sbt.jar"
```

Comment: The path to .jar file seems to contain quotes: \"1.0.4"\

Comment: do you think that is what is causing the issue? Do you know how to get ride of those quotes? I tried renaming that folder but no avail

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125749/installing-sbt-on-windows-10-for-scala-course

Comment: I don't think the problem is in those quotes. How did you install sbt?

Comment: @laughedelic I got it from here for windows http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html, and just followed through with the installation wizard.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I am using the most recent version 1.0.4. I also tried getting the installer from http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Windows.html (with this version, it throws this instead "....\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\_TO_BE_REPLACED\jars\sbt.jar" I have no idea where the TO_BE_REPLACED came from (it's not in the path)

Comment: @Smartk8 Thank you for the link. In my project, it says in the build "sbt.version=0.13.16"

The sbt version I just installed is 0.13.16 (but as mentioned above, the path is still off, and added in "TO_BE_REPLACED" instead of a version number)

Comment: but it's right there when i follow it manually in file explorer.  ...\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.16\jars

I also tried adding sbt to the path in environment variables